# GET returns 400 in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

```
req_url = 'http://www.example.com/' 

request = {
    "view":"ecpcisqeddscat:_deals_tearsheet_bic",
    "address":"10.51.0.104:9090",
    "metadatastore":"",
    "keytype":"key",
    "rowkeys":str(["154083204960","154083277473"]),
    "simplifyresult":str(False),
    "haslQuery":""
}

headers = {
    "Host": "nycssnsqa3.amers.ime.reuters.com",
    "Accept": "* / *",
    "Content - Type": "application / json",
    "User - Agent": "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; Win64;x64) AppleWebKit "
    "/ 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 67.0.3396.79  Safari / 537.36"
}

headers.update(request)
session = requests.Session()
session.headers = headers
r = session.get(req_url)

print(r.url)
print(r)

if r.status_code == 200:
    return r.json()
```

It outputs

```
<Response [400]>
None
```

I think there is some problem in the request part but I am not able to figure out what it is. In the website it has been passed as a header parameter in the GET request.

Comment: The request dict doesnt look like something which will go in headers. It will either be part of your get params or this is a post request.

Comment: @MohitC How to make it as part of my get params in Python

Comment: header = { "Accept": "* / *",
                    "Content - Type": "application / json",
                    "User - Agent": "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; Win64;x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 67.0.3396.79  Safari / 537.36"}

        param  = {"view":"ecpcisqeddscat:_deals_tearsheet_bic","address":"10.51.0.104:9090","metadatastore":"","keytype":"key","rowkeys":str(["154083204960","154083277473"]),"simplifyresult":str(False),"haslQuery":""}

               r = requests.get(self.req_url,params=param, headers=header)

Comment: still getting the same 404 error

Comment: Esha in your session.get send another param as params=request